# The behavior of the for loop split between switch cases

Tags: c++, c, duffs-device

While playing with the code I've noticed a strange behavior that I do not know to explain the logic behind

```
void foo(int n)
{
    int m = n;
    while (--n > 0)
    {
        switch (n)
        {
            case -1:
            case 0:
                for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            default:
                    printf(":-)");
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo(10);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the `printf` to execute let's say `10` times. Then I saw it continues to run (imagine 100000 instead of 10) and supposed that the developers (VS) interpreted the `printf` **inside** the `for` (pretty expected), hence the output is made `n` times for each entrance to `switch`.

But then turned out `j` was never initialized.

So my question is why ? Is this an undefined behavior? Is not this a, supposedly, standard code?

Comment: _"Is this an undefined behavior? Is not this a, supposedly, standard code?"_ Nope, the behavior is well known and even used at purpose with the famous _Duff's device_ for loop unrolling within a small range of values (looks slightly different though).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Skipping `j`'s initialization leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @John Yeah, but generally mixing `switch` `case` labels with loops is OK, that's not the primary reason for UB here.

Comment: The reason your compiler is happy with the odd looking placement of `for` is that each `switch()` `case` does  not define a separate block (scope). So as odd as it looks, it is legal..

Comment: Protothreads might serve as a good example of how this technique can be utilized (with explanation in the docs). It's kinda hackish, but seems reasonable in case of bare-metal embedded devices:
http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/expansion.html

Comment: It's worth noting that MSVC issues a warning that the initialization of j is skipped by 'default' label.  As an interesting side note to that, pulling the declaration of j out into a separate statement: `int j;` `for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)` silences the warning, but does not make the problem go away.

Comment: @dgnuff, you are totally right. I've just ignored it. It even have a very detailed explanation.

Comment: You ask about standards, but you tag this with both C and C++—two separate languages defined by two separate standards. Which set of standards are we supposed to hold this to?

Comment: @alagner: "kinda hackish"?  Wow, I used to write C code for Z-80 embedded devices where 32kb (kilobytes) was our large memory option (we shipped one device with a whopping 48kb once).  I never got this hackish. Code should be written so that it's readable by the next human that needs to maintain it.

Comment: "May the goto live forever!" ;-) Jumping inside a loop makes Nassi-Shneiderman happy!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`default` is just a label (address to where the code jumps if `n` is not -1 or 0).
Thus when `n` is not -1 or 0, the flow enters the body of the `for` loop skipping the initialisation of `j`. You can write the same code also as this, so it would be clearer what is happening here:

```
int m = n;
while (--n > 0)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case -1:
        case 0:
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            {
        default: printf(":-)");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

(Note, as mentioned by @alagner in the comments, it won't compile with C++ compiler but perfectly compiles with C one so this is good enough to make my point and explain how the code looks).

So yes, since `j` is uninitialised, it is undefined behaviour.
If you enable compiler warnings, it will warn you about it (https://godbolt.org/z/rzGraP):

```
warning: 'j' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   12 |                 for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
      |                          ^
```

Comment: Or even fails to build when compiled as C++. I'm no "language lawyer", but looks like it's the point when then C vs C++ subtleties start to manifest:
https://godbolt.org/z/MhjxGG

Comment: @alagner You are right. C++ is much more strict in such cases. The OP tagged the question as C and C++ so I went with C. But I'll add your note to my answer.

Answer (score 11):

A `switch` block is effectively a glorified set of `goto` statements. The different cases don't introduce scopes or any logical structure to the code. They're really just targets for the `switch` statement to jump to.

In this program, the `default:` label is inside a nested `for` loop. When the `default` case is hit the program jumps inside the loop as if there were a `goto` statement there. The `switch` block is equivalent to:

```
if (n == -1 || n == 0) {
    goto before_loop;
}
else {
    goto inside_loop;
}

before_loop:
for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
    inside_loop:
    printf(":-)");
}
```

This is dangerous because jumping to `inside_loop:` skips over `j = 0`. As you've observed, `j` is still declared but it's not initialized, and accessing it leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7):

As posted, the code has undefined behavior because when the `switch` jumps to the `default:` label, inside the `for` statement body, it skips the initialization of `j` in the inner loop, causing undefined behavior when `j` is tested and decremented when the loop iterates.

Skipping the initialization with a direct jump into a new scope is not allowed in C++. Such a constraint is not present in the C language, for compatibility with historical code where is does not necessarily cause problems, but modern compilers detect this error and complain. I recommend using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to avoid silly mistakes.

Note that modified as below, it becomes fully defined, prints `:)` 90 times (9 iterations of the outer loop, times 10 iterations of the inner loop) and finishes successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int n) {
    int m = n;
    while (--n > 0) {
        int j = 0;
        switch (n) {
            case -1:
            case 0:
                for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            default:
                    printf(":-)");
                break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    foo(10);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For starters, the function `foo` having the return type `int` returns nothing.

The `while` loop:

```
while (--n > 0)
{
    //..
}
```

gets control only in the case when the value of the pre-decrement expression `--n` is greater than `0`.

That is, within the `while` loop, the variable `n` is neither equal to `0` nor to `-1`.

So, control will be passed at once to the label `default` within the `switch` statement.

```
    switch (n)
    {
        case -1:
        case 0:
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        default:
                printf(":-)");
            break;
    }
```

You may equivalently rewrite the `while` loop without the `switch` statement the following way to make it clearer:

```
while (--n > 0)
{
    goto Default;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
    {
        Default: printf(":-)");
    } 
}
```

That is, control is at once passed inside the `for` loop. According to the C Standard (6.8.5 Iteration statements)

> 4 An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be
> executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to
> 0. **The repetition occurs regardless of whether the loop body is entered
> from the iteration statement or by a jump**.

It means that the `for` loop will contain one statement:

```
printf(":-)");
```

will be executed.

However, the initial initialization of the variable `j` in the `for` loop is bypassed. From the C Standard (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 6 For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
> its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
> associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an
> enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
> execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively,
> a new instance of the object is created each time. The initial value
> of the object is indeterminate. **If an initialization is specified
> for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound
> literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value
> becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.**

So, the variable `j`  has indeterminate value. It means that the `for` loop and, as a result, the function itself, have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of good explanations, but the key point is missing: that the compiler places a `jmp` instruction after the `printf` statement because it just compiled a `for` statement. The `jmp` jumps to the condition of the loop and continues there (using an uninitialized `j`).

Comment: Indeed, this was the key piece of information I was missing to understand the behavior. (Well, I guessed it from reading the other answers, but I'm surprised none of them thought to mention it.)

Comment: Those who can (display and understand) would view the assember code of the function. And a note: `j` is undefined even before the jump to the loop condition in the `default` case.